# Not able to create record in All subscribers via SQL query activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, subscriber-key

Greetings of the day!
I am trying to create record in All subscribers via SQL query activity: below is my SQL query

```
**select Email as 'Email Address',
Email  as 'Subscriber Key',
[First Name] as 'Full Name',
[Master User] as 'Master User'
From [Filtered_DE_JB2]**
```

here Full name and Master user are set as the required field in All Subscribers and "Filtered_DE_JB2" is my filtered data extension. There are two records in it that I am trying to insert in All Subscribers. Kindly guide me on how to achieve this.

Regards Shaileshk

Comment: What data action are using on your target DE?

Comment: Append - Data action I am using